# Failed to create snap, snap command failed

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-linux

I am trying to build a snap and i have used flutter for building the app. while creating the snap package i am getting an error.

```sh
Staging flutter-extension 
+ snapcraftctl stage
Staging gnome-3-28-extension 
+ snapcraftctl stage
Staging system-information 
+ snapcraftctl stage
Priming flutter-extension 
+ snapcraftctl prime
Priming gnome-3-28-extension 
+ snapcraftctl prime
Priming system-information 
+ snapcraftctl prime
The command 'system_information' for 'system_information' was resolved to 'bin/system_information'.
The command 'system_information' has been changed to 'bin/system_information'.
Snapping |                                                                                                   
Failed to create snap, snap command failed:
stdout:

stderr:
error: cannot pack "/root/prime": mksquashfs call failed: Could not create destination file: Operation not permitted

We would appreciate it if you anonymously reported this issue.
No other data than the traceback and the version of snapcraft in use will be sent.
Would you like to send this error data? (Yes/No/Always/View) [no]: no
snapcraft-system-information #
```

I have tried snapcraft clean already but it didn't cleared the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error is generating from multipass which i used to build my snap packages. I tried deleting /build and building again but it didn't worked.

I found an alternate way to build snaps using [lxd](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/linux#install-lxd)

Answer (score 2):

**Delete build directory and build again.**

follow this github link for detail
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4885